# Controller in angular can't be initialized globally after 1.3

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn Controllers and Scopes in AngularJs, but I always get this `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'studentController' is not a function, got undefined`, when I run this code.

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>AngularJs</title>
    <script src="script/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
        <div class="container" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <br>
            <h2>List name using ng-init and ng-repeat</h2>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : name | orderBy:'city' ">
                    {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function studentController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name : 'John Smit', city : 'Ifrane'},
                {name : 'Nurcan Turkey', city : 'Izmir'},
                {name : 'Laura Keller', city : 'Cologne'},
                {name : 'Sam Haimoura', city : 'Harhoura'},
                {name : 'Brayan Amid', city : 'Casablanca'}
            ];
        };
    </script>

</body>
```

Even though this code is somehow directly from a tutorial. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code

Comment: You should bootstrap angularjs first, read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00#bootstrapping-angularjs-apps)

Comment: what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: The above code seems to work well enough in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nde4m2ff/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="appname" ng-controller="StudentController">
var app = angular.module('appname', []);
app.controller('StudentController','');
```

Answer (score 4):

ng-app shouldn't be empty

```
<div ng-app="appname" ng-controller="StudentController">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('appname', []);
app.controller('StudentController', ...
```

Comment: Where is `appname` defined?

Comment: In the html: div ng-app="appname"'

Comment: Then you should say so in your answer, because in the question this is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJs</title>
    <script src="script/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
        <div class="container" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <br>
            <h2>List name using ng-init and ng-repeat</h2>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : name | orderBy:'city' ">
                    {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('studentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name : 'John Smit', city : 'Ifrane'},
                {name : 'Nurcan Turkey', city : 'Izmir'},
                {name : 'Laura Keller', city : 'Cologne'},
                {name : 'Sam Haimoura', city : 'Harhoura'},
                {name : 'Brayan Amid', city : 'Casablanca'}
            ];
        }]);
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you pleas add a short explanation of why you think this solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks, but do u know why the other one was not working for me, but it was working on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of angular are you using? With angular 1.3, you cannot use global functions as a controller. You can see a list of breaking changes [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

You can override this behavior by using allowGlobals (More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)) but I won't recommend that.

Comment: agree, a bad behavior.

Comment: I am using version 1.3

Answer (score 0):

The above code seems to work well enough in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nde4m2ff/.

I believe the problem may be that you initializing angularjs too early in the page. Try moving the angular script definition to the end, after you've defined `function studentController() { }`.

Comment: Lool, I hated seeing that working there, cause it is also working in the video tutorial I was watching. I moved that script many times, but no result :(

Answer (score 0):

Try defining an **app** and using a different **notation**, ng-app should not be empty, by using the array [notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) is recommended by the angular team like the following:

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>AngularJs</title>
    <script src="script/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentController">
        <div class="container" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <br>
            <h2>List name using ng-init and ng-repeat</h2>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : name | orderBy:'city' ">
                    {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    angular.module('myapp').controller('studentController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
                {name : 'John Smit', city : 'Ifrane'},
                {name : 'Nurcan Turkey', city : 'Izmir'},
                {name : 'Laura Keller', city : 'Cologne'},
                {name : 'Sam Haimoura', city : 'Harhoura'},
                {name : 'Brayan Amid', city : 'Casablanca'}
            ];
        }
    ]);
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain what is different.

Comment: This did not work as well, but the one from @Mike worked fine. thank you anyways

Comment: @LutzHorn I just wrote my answer before mike's, both answers address the issue in a very similar way.

Comment: Yes, but none of you both explained the difference.