# Angularjs app not bootstrapping without module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs and this might sound very silly but I want to know why my angularjs app won't bootstrap without making a module even though egghead.io and several tutorials showing otherwise.
Here is my HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the controller.js file which **DOESN'T WORKS**

```
function HelloController($scope) {
$scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

When i register the module [and naming the ng-app as 'hello' ofcourse] and write a controller it **works**

```
angular.module('hello', []).controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
});
```

I just want to know the reason for this behavior. 
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: If you search this on SO, you should find the same question just asked few minutes ago.

Comment: Link to that question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152801/controller-in-angular-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This is a breaking change of angular 1.3. You can see a list of breaking changes [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Because of this change, you cannot use global functions as a controller. You can override this behavior by using allowGlobals (More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)) but I won't recommend that.